# How can i prevent divs from moving while resizing the page

Tags: html, css

im creating a new website and im noob at html and css, thats my first website, but i searched a lot about how to create a website.

But when i resize the window from the browser, all divs move automatically.

My website: http://teteste.herobo.com/ - The language is portuguese, but you can understand whats happening.

As you can see, when you resize the window, the divs change automatically, is there any way to prevent divs from moving while resizing the page?

My Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Armata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<title>AngoBooks</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.g1').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 'fast');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.5}, 'slow');
    });

});

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;
var path = new Array();

path[0] = "imagens/1.png";
path[1] = "imagens/2.png";
path[2] = "imagens/3.png";

var k = path.length-1; 

var caption = new Array();


caption[0] = "Primeira descrição";
caption[1] = "Segunda descrição";
caption[2] = "Terceira descrição";


function swapImage(){
var el = document.getElementById("mydiv");
el.innerHTML=caption[i];
var img= document.getElementById("slide");
img.src= path[i];


if(i < k ) { i++;} 
else  { i = 0; }
setTimeout("swapImage()",5000);


}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
window.onload = func;
} else {
window.onload = function() {
if (oldonload) {
oldonload();
}
func();
}
}
}



addLoadEvent(function() {
swapImage();


}); 
</script>




<body>

<div class="cbc">
<div id="redes">


<div style="width:90%; solid #000;">
<div style="float:left; width:33.3%;">
      <div align="center"><img src="imagens/facebook.png" height="40" width="40" />
        <img src="imagens/twitter.png" height="40" width="40" />
        <img src="imagens/g+.png" height="40" width="40" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%;">

    <form method="POST" action="http://YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE:81/login/login.php">
  <div align="right"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="'Armata', sans-serif">Utilizador:</font>
  <input type="text" name="Utilizador" size="15" />

      </div>
</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%;"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="'Armata', sans-serif">Password:</font> <input type="text" name="username" size="15" />


    <button type="submit" value="Login" class="botao">Entrar</button>

    <button type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="botao">Registar</button></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>


</div></div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="principal">
<div class="centered-block">
        <a href="/" class="logo-lnk">
          <img src="imagens/logo.png"/>
        </a> 
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="white">Ínicio</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="white">Categorias</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="white">Outros produtos</font></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><font color="white">Carrinho</font></a></li>
        <div id="divisoria"></div>
    </ul>

</nav>
</div>
  <div class="subtitulo">

<p><font color="white">Vendemos Online, desde 2011, os melhores livros</p>

<p> do mercado em Angola, encomende já o seu.</font></p>
</div>

<div id="slideshow">

<body>
<img name="slide" id="slide" alt ="my images" height="300" width="900" src="imagens/1.png"/>
<div id="mydiv"></div>


  <script>
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.color="white";
</script>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="width:100%; padding: 160px 0 10px 0;">

<div style="clear:both;"></div>



<div style="width:100%; padding: 3px 0 10px 0;">
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; height:28px; background-image:url(imagens/titulo.png)"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; height:28px;"><p align="center"><font size="6" color="#ff7c00" face="'Roboto', sans-serif"> Principais categorias </p></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%; height:28px; background-image:url(imagens/titulo.png)"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>




</div>

<div class="fade1">
<img src="imagens/g1.png" alt="foto" class="g1" />
<img src="imagens/g2.png" alt="foto" class="g1" />
</div>

<div class="fade2">
<img src="imagens/g3.png" alt="foto" class="g1"/>
<img src="imagens/g4.png" alt="foto" class="g1"/>
<img src="imagens/g5.png" alt="foto" class="g1"/>
</div>





<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="creditos">
<div class="empresa">

<div style="width:90%; solid #000; position:relative;">
    <div style="float:left; width:25%;"><h1 align="left"



    ><font color="#A66100">Atendimento</font></h1>
      <div align="left">
        <ul id="atendimento">
          <li>Contacte-nos</li>
          <li>Devoluções</li>
          <li>Mapa do site</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
<ul id="atendimento">
</ul></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%;"><h1 align="left">Conta</h1>
      <div align="left">
        <ul id="Conta">
          <li>Conta</li>
          <li>Histórico de Pedido</li>
          <li>Newsletter</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
<ul id="Conta">
</ul></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%;"><h1 align="left">Extras</h1>
      <div align="center">
        <ul id="Extras">
          <li>
            <div align="left">Fabricantes
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div align="left">Vale Presente
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div align="left">Promoções</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul id="Extras">
</ul></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%;"><div class="informacao">
<h1 align="left">Informação</h1>
<div align="left">
  <ul id="info">
    <li>Sobre nós</li>
    <li>Sobre as Encomendas</li>
    <li>Termos e Condições</li>
  </ul>

</div>
<ul id="info">
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>


<div style="width:100%; padding: 0px 0 10px 0;">
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; height:18px;><div id="redessociais">
</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; height:18px;"><div class="developer">Copyright © 2013 AngoBooks. Todos os direitos reservados. <br> Site desenvolvido por: Rúben Diogo.</p></div></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%; height:18px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Css code:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 div#principal {
    background-image:url(../estrutura/bg.png);
    height:410px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:100%;
}
 #menu ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:23px;
    text-aligne:center;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:enter !important;
    left:162px;
    float:right;
    font-family:'Armata', sans-serif;
}
 #menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}
 #menu ul li a {
    padding:2px 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    z- ndex:12;
    horizontal-align:middle;
}
 #menu ul li a:hover {
    color:white;
    border-bottom:3px solid white;
}
 .logo-lnk {
    width:250px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
 .logo-lnk img {
    width:100%;
    border:0;
}
 .centered-block {
    width:987px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:23px 0 20px 0;
}
 div#divisoria {
    height:1px;
    weight:100%;
    background:white;
}
 .subtitulo {
    padding:56px 0 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-shadow:0.0em 0.0em 0.01em #FFB873;
}
 .g1 {
    background:none;
}
 .g1:hover {
    background:#0000ff;
}
 .fade1 {
    padding:10px 0 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
 .fade2 {
    text-align:center;
}
 div#slideshow {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
 div#mydiv {
    background-color:#ff7c00;
    width:900px;
    font-family:'Armata', sans-serif;
}
 .creditos {
    background-image:url(../estrutura/bg2.png);
    height:75px;
    weight:100%;
    padding:90px 0 20px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
 .empresa {
    list-style-type:none;
    color:#A66400;
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px }
 ul#atendimento {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
 ul#Extras {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
 ul#Conta {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
 ul#info {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:13px;
}
 div#titulo {
    background-image:url(../imagens/titulo.png);
    width:100%;
    height:28px;
}
 .facebook {
    text-align:left;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
 .youtube {
    text-align:left;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
 .twitter {
    text-align:left;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
 .developer {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#bebebe;
    text-align:center;
}
 div#redes {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:url(../imagens/bgg.jpg);
    z-index:30;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
 .cbc {
    height:40px;
}
 .botao {
    background-color:#ff7c00;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Armata', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
body { min-width: 750px; }
```

(adjust the width to your needs).
When the browser window gets smaller than 750px, the horizontal scrollbars will appear.

Comment: No problem, please don't forget to mark the answer as the solution.

Comment: This does not work for me, my `<div>`s still collapse to the next line on the navbar. They are set to `display: inline-block;`, and I set the minimum `<body>` `width` to equal the total `width` of the navbar icons. However, they just start to populate below eachother when resizing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In response to my last post: I am sorry, I was pressing the wrong command to refresh the page... was pressing Alt-R so many times on my linux machine yesterday, I got back on my Mac and it wasn't refreshing!

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the header and footer to stop getting wider add:

```
.class{max-width:960px}/*or whatever you want the px to be*/
```

If you're wanting them to not get smaller add: (like what LinkinTED has)

```
.class{min-width:960px}/*or whatever you want the px to be*/
```

If you want it to always be the same width:

```
.class{width:960px}
```

It all depends on what you want. `.class` could be your body, or whatever wraps all your html body elements.

Answer (score -3):

I tried it on your site an seems it works!

```
body { 
    width: 100%; 
}
```